# Dubai transit visa for non Dubai based airlines

Tags: visas, dubai

I am travelling from India to Europe and have a halt for 48 hours while going and 12 hours while returning. I am travelling by a non Dubai based airline (Etihad or Emirates). How can I get a transit visa as my flight bookings and hotel bookings are already done?

Comment: You can typically apply via the relevant airline’s website eg https://www.etihad.com/en-gb/before-you-fly/visas/ and https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/prearranged-uae-visas.aspx

Comment: but my flight is neither in etihad or emirates..so can i still get visa from them?

Comment: AFAIK yes. Try clicking on the links

Comment: Which airline did you use?

Comment: i used spice jet(indian carrier) and pegasus (to amsterdam). had i been aware of this issue, i would have gone for emirates.